# ByteArrayInputStream cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I have method which is going return the values that are going to displayed as text string.So what i'm doing is converting to `ByteArrayInputStream`.

```
public String method() {
    inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(prod().getBytes());
    return method;
}
```

`prod()` is a method which going to return the values. It is giving me an error `ByteArrayInputStream cannot be resolved to a type`. Please advise.

Comment: `import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;`

Comment: Bookmark [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

Comment: Never use the raw String.getBytes() method - always specify a character set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Import `ByteArrayInputStream` from the `java.io` package so that the unqualified class is available to the application:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
```